# Change Fragment on setOnItemClickListener to ListView with CardView

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, cardview

I have a ListView that uses a CardView to inflate it's layout. When the user clicks on the the first item in the ListView, this should change the Fragment. However, I am unsure of how to do this. I attempted to change the Fragment in the adapter class (CustomAdapter.java) and it didn't work. I also have tried doing this in the Fragment the ListView is in but it didn't work either (the app didn't crash when I clicked one of the items - nothing happened):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (position) {

                case 0:
                    fragment = new DesignsWorkshopFragment();

                    break;

            }

            if (fragment != null) {

                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);

                ft.addToBackStack(null);

                ft.commit();
            }

        }
    });
```

---

**SuppliersFragment.java:**

```
public class SuppliersFragment extends Fragment {

CustomAdapter adapter;
ListView lv;


public SuppliersFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_suppliers, container, false);

    lv = view.findViewById(R.id.lvFragmentSuppliers);

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(), getData());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (position) {

                case 0:
                    fragment = new DesignsWorkshopFragment();

                    break;

            }

            if (fragment != null) {

                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);

                ft.addToBackStack(null);

                ft.commit();
            }

        }
    });

    return view;
}

private ArrayList getData() {

    ArrayList<SuppliersCardview> suppliersCardview = new ArrayList<>();

    SuppliersCardview s = new SuppliersCardview();
    s.setThumbnail(R.drawable.designs_workshop_logo);
    s.setName("Designs Workshop");
    suppliersCardview.add(s);

    s = new SuppliersCardview();
    s.setThumbnail(R.drawable.organic_clothing_logo);
    s.setName("Organic Clothing Industries");
    suppliersCardview.add(s);

    s = new SuppliersCardview();
    s.setThumbnail(R.drawable.suns_sewing_ltd);
    s.setName("Sun's Sewing Ltd");
    suppliersCardview.add(s);

    return suppliersCardview;
}}
```

**CustomAdapter.java:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context c;
ArrayList<SuppliersCardview> suppliersCardview;

public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<SuppliersCardview> suppliersCardview) {
    this.c = c;
    this.suppliersCardview = suppliersCardview;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return suppliersCardview.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return suppliersCardview.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.cardview_layout, parent, false);
    }

    final SuppliersCardview s = (SuppliersCardview) this.getItem(position);

    ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivSupplierLogo);
    TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSupplierName);

    imageView.setImageResource(s.getThumbnail());
    textView.setText(s.getName());

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Attempted to change fragment here in a switch statement

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

**SuppliersCardview.java:**

```
public class SuppliersCardview {

private String name;
private int thumbnail;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getThumbnail() {
    return thumbnail;
}

public void setThumbnail(int thumbnail) {
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}}
```

---

**SuppliersFragment XML:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.miguelpeachey.marketplacesimulator.Fragments.SuppliersFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBrowseSuppliersHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#bfbdbd"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_sans"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Browse Suppliers"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ListView
       android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/lvFragmentSuppliers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/colorTransparent"
        android:dividerHeight="20dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**CardView XML:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_margin="40dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
app:ignore="NamespaceTypo"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#cccbcb"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSupplierLogo"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSupplierName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivSupplierLogo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/brawler"
        android:text="Supplier"
        android:textColor="#232323"
        android:textSize="22sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

So how can I replace/change fragments on the ListView's item click that uses a CardView as its layout? Other people's solutions did not help me.

I have used [this website](https://camposha.info/source/android-custom-cardview-listview-source) as a tutorial to create the CardView and inflate the ListView's layout (some code here is from the website).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by just removing

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

in my **CustomAdapter.java** class.

Answer (score 0):

You have your object of fragment now you need to use fragment manager and replace existing fragment with fragment you want to show.

```
DesignsWorkshopFragment fragment2=new DesignsWorkshopFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getActivity().getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main,fragment2,"tag");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Only creating your fragment's instance will not show it in activity.

Comment: Is this in listView.setOnItemClickListener(...)? 

If so, the the current code I have in there works, just not in SuppliersFragment.java.

Answer (score 0):

Adding and replacing of fragment is done inside activity.You need to notify your activity  on the click of item view in your ListView.This can be done using interfaces.

create one interface:

```
public interface ClickListener{
  public void onClick();
   }
```

Implement this interface in your activity.And when you are creating the Fragment pass "this" as reference inside fragment's constructor.Like this :

```
  fragment = new DesignsWorkshopFragment(this);
```

Inside fragment, you need to  create the interface reference.

```
private ClickListener clickListener ;
```

Inside fragment initialize this interface reference

```
DesignsWorkshopFragment(ClickListener clickListener){
this.clickListener = clickListener;
}
```

Now do the same thing when you are creating adapter.

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(), getData(),clickListener);
```

Inside adapter create and intialize interface reference.

```
 private ClickListener clickListener ;

 public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<SuppliersCardview> suppliersCardview,
                       ClickListener clickListener ) {
  this.c = c;
  this.suppliersCardview = suppliersCardview;
  this.clickListener = clickListener;
  }
```

and whenever a click is happening. just call the interface method.

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       clickListener.onClick();
    }
});
```

this will give a callback inside your activity's interfcae implementation. In here

```
public void onClick(){
 //write your code for adding or replacing fragment.
}
```

Comment: I can already replace fragments in other fragments using the code I showed in my list view.setOnItemClickListener(...). So, I don't know if this would help, will try, though.

Comment: I don't how will you do that,but that is not a good practice.Fragments are managed by activity.so you should do that there only.